# How to use Amazon S3 bucket through web browser (not console)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an amazon s3 bucket. I am planning to use like Google Drive. I mean How can I  access my bucket directly through a web browser, Navigate to its folder, download the files it has. Upload the new folders and files etc. With different users having different permission to access the bucket.

I don't want the bucket to be accessible only by AWS console, rather it should be accessible from your web browser. let me know if it's possible?

thank you,

Comment: But you can access the was console through your web browser: https://aws.amazon.com/de/console/ You can setup IAM users for access control. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a utility like [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) will meet your needs.

It provides a graphical interface to S3 (and FTP, etc) and you can drag & drop files to upload/download.

Just provide it with your Access Key and Secret Key and it will connect for you. No need to login to the AWS console.